# Need to override Search Filter url param (_search) in jgrid the jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php

Hi I have created a user message page with this plugin.
The grid will show the user inbox and the user outbox(sent) messages. here's a little code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

       //...some stuff
       currentURL = function() {

            return 'json_member_mail.php?task='+ currentBox;
                    //where current box is either inbox or outbox
       }

       //... alot of stuff

       myGrid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

        url:currentURL(),
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',

        //      even more stuff  ....

       }).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', 
        { 
                        the lil stuff....

            search:true,

                        //the dialog...
                 }

         // the dialog form editing whatever...

   );//grid


});//document.ready
```

so then when the user clicks on outbox something like this happens:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ url:currentURL(), postData:{lrt:lastReloadTime} }).trigger("reloadGrid"); //where current URL has the GET param task=outbox
```

it working all great until I use my search filters. for example I search for the messages sent from the user 'foo' and it's all good but when I click on outbox it will still try to show me messages sent by the user 'foo' but I want the search filters to be reset.

I tried loading the search dialog on document ready and closing it immediately to get the filter().reset and all that but it doesn't work :the-built-in-search-filter-box

myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid'); has the same behaviour as well

```
.jqGrid('setGridParam',{    url:currentURL(), postData:{_search:'false'} }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

would fix my problem but it won't override the _search param.

any generous suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol, So I made one of those stupid mistakes...
where in the original message I say "// the dialog form editing whatever..." I made a mistake
yeah I didn't even bother to write that part on here so what I had there was:

```
}).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', 
        { 
            edit:false,
            add:false,
            del:false,
            search: true,
            refresh:true,
            refreshtext:"Refresh",
            searchtext:"Search"
        },
        {},//add 
        {}, //edit
        {}, //delete
            {},  <---instead of putting search options on this line
        {        <----I was putting it here on this line
            overlay:false,
            closeOnEscape:true,
                        afterShowSearch:... , 
        } /* allow the view dialog to be closed when user press ESC key*/
    );//grid
```

however I realized that after I fixed my problem with a hack when I saw the overlay:false was not working and there was still a jQuery UI overlay for search...

what I did might be helpful somehow to someone who reads this one day so what I did was:

there is a get parameter nd that is a Unix Timestamp(POSIX) but in miliseconds (javascripts implementation) unlike php and mysql and most unix stuff (which is in seconds). I also sent a timestamp of the last time any of the navigation links where clicked:

```
lastReloadTime = new Date().getTime() ;
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ 
        url:currentURL(), 
        postData:{lrt:lastReloadTime
}
```

then in my php file that generates the json data:

```
$searchOK = 1;

if($_GET['_search']=='true') {

    if( isset($_GET['lrt']) ){ 

    //so here I check to see if the main mail links have been clicked at all
    //from the time of the first page load 
    //if not then its all good but if it has check for the time

        if(   (    ($_GET['nd']/1000)-($_GET['lrt']/1000)    ) < 1) $searchOK=0;
    }

    if($searchOK){ //you can do search since it might be going through pages of a search result
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use no function call as avalue of the `url` parameter. The value of the parameter will be caclulated only once during the grid initialization. Instead of that you can use

```
url: 'json_member_mail.php',
postData: {
    task: function() {/* return currentBox based on criterias which you have */},
    lrt: lastReloadTime
}
```

If needed you can make the property `lrt` also as a function.

If some property of `postData` are functions **the function will be called on any ajax request**. So you can use **really actual** value of the `currentBox` on searching, paging, sorting or page reload.

If you need reload jqGrid you will no more need to change `url` or `postData` and you can just call `trigger("reloadGrid")` only.